# Pseudodifferential operators on compact manifolds with boundary

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, pseudo-differential-operators

I have heard that the square root of the Dirichlet (or the Neumann) Laplacian is not a pseudodifferential operator on compact manifolds with boundary. The context in which this was said was that spectral multipliers of square root of the Laplacian do not give usual Calderon-Zygmund $L^p$-continuity results.

I am wondering: what goes wrong in the presence of a boundary? Can we define the square root of the Laplacian as a pseudodifferential operator, but the continuity results do not hold, or is the square root of the Laplacian not a pseudodifferential operator at all?

Comment: I suggest looking for notes by Richard Melrose or Rafe Mazzeo about pseudodifferential operators on a manifold with boundary.